# Почему могут слипаться фотографии карточек товара в Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

Скриншот, на котором видна проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего там не слипается, счётчик посешений накручиваете? Добавте код.

Comment: посмотрите скрин

Answer (score 3):

Карточки слипаются из-за неправильно заданных стилей. Стили страницы заданы таким образом, чтобы на страницу помещались 4 карточки, но помещаются лишь 3(на моём ноутбуке 1366x768). У последней(четвёртой) карточки в ряду добавлен класс `.last`, у которого нету правого отступа, но карточка переносится в ряд ниже, из-за чего и появляется эффект слипания. Используйте либо фиксированную длину блоков для каждого из размеров экрана при помощи [@Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), либо используйте более современный [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
#left-area ul.products {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 !important;
    line-height: 1.7 !important;
    list-style: none !important;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

При этом, вам нужно убрать классы `.last` и `.first` со всех карточек.

**Совет:** старайтесь использовать изображения товаров и категорий товаров так, чтобы у них были одинаковые свойства `width` и `height`. Для этого делайте блоки с товарами одинаковой ширины и высоты, а для изображений внутри используйте свойство `object-fit: fill`

Comment: тоесть проще прописать отступ для класса .last ?

Comment: Конечно, это будет проще, но это не гарантирует, что всё будет отображаться нормально на мобильных устройствах или на устройствах с необычным размером экрана.